# Insert Columns of Numbers to Existing File with Python

Tags: python

I am looking to take a file like the one below:

input_file

```
H          3.75789        1.31181        0.94185
H          3.75997        1.37155       -0.86433
H          5.02067       -0.84758        0.87489
H          5.89984        0.47166        0.01279
H          5.02304       -0.78890       -0.93545
```

and add columns of "1" to the file:

output_file

```
H 3.75789 1  1.31181 1  0.94185 1
H 3.75997 1  1.37155 1 -0.86433 1
H 5.02067 1 -0.84758 1  0.87489 1
H 5.89984 1  0.47166 1  0.01279 1
H 5.02304 1 -0.78890 1 -0.93545 1
```

The spacing I provided in the desired output is the minimum formatting I would need. Specifically, I need at least one white space between the columns.

I have achieved this with `awk` in a bash script (though not with the same white space) by doing:

```
awk '{ printf("%s %10.5f %3d %10.5f %3d %10.5f %3d\n", $1,$2,1,$3,1,$4,1) }' input_file > output_file
```

My question is, how can I transfer this over to python? Or does there exist a better way to do this in python? Please let me know if you need any additional information, or how to improve the question.

Comment: Can you not just read the file line-by-line, add the string `" 1"` to each line, and write it to another file again?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have three columns that I need to insert.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: Well then, (1) read one line, (2) split it, (3) insert "1"s, (4) join to a single string again, (5) write to file

Comment: @mkrieger1 That’s what I was thinking, but wasn’t sure if there was an easier or more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for this.

1. numpy.genfromtxt to load the data
2. numpy.ones and numpy.hstack to create and append a column of 1s
3. numpy.savetxt to write a text file to disk.

Somethink like:

```
import numpy as np

the_data = np.genfromtxt("input_file", dtype=str)
the_ones = np.ones(the_data.shape[0]).astype(int)
result_data = np.hstack((the_data, the_ones.reshape((the_ones.size, 1)).astype(str)))
print(result_data)
np.savetxt("output_file", result_data, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: This only inserts a single column of  "1" at then end of the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to achieve the desired output

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv(‘<file_name>’, sep=‘\t’, header=None)
DF[4] = 1 # assuming there are four columns in your original file as shown above
DF.to_csv(‘<file_name>’, sep=‘ ‘, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Will this work even though I’m not using a CSV files?

Comment: Yes, you can read txt, xlsx, all kinds of files into a DF using read_csv, read_excel methods.